Reduce TPU RAM usage when masking pytorch tensors
Currently working on merging LLMs and computing their task vectors in Tensor. (by getting the top 80% of vectors) But every time when I try to get the value from tensors it exceeds the RAM usage of Colab TPUs. The tensor is huge but will only take around 60GB of RAM. Is there any way to reduce the TPU RAM usage at this stage?
def mask(tensor):
    with torch.no_grad():
        d=tensor.shape[1]
        mask=int(d*0.8)
        tensor_abs=tensor.abs()
    
        #RAM usage is good until the next line
        
        kth_values, _ = tensor_abs.kthvalue(mask, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        mask = tensor_abs >= kth_values
        return tensor*mask

I have tried using torch.no_grad. Is there any way to turn tensor to different batches and deal with them speratly?
